# python3-dev and libssl-dev installation failed on ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, apt, python, python3

Tried to install `python3-dev` and `libssl-dev` on a new Ubuntu 18.04 with:

```
$ sudo apt install libssl-dev python3-dev
```

But i get the following **Error**:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libssl-dev : Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.0g-2ubuntu4) but 1.1.1-1ubuntu2.1~18.04.4 is to be installed
              Recommends: libssl-doc but it is not going to be installed
python3-dev : Depends: python3 (= 3.6.5-3) but 3.6.7-1~18.04 is to be installed
              Depends: libpython3-dev (= 3.6.5-3) but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: python3.6-dev (>= 3.6.5-2~) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

What could cause this issue, and how to fix it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I restore the default repositories?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories) as I can't reproduce it on clean 18.04 LTS VM.

Comment: Show your current apt repositories. `cat /etc/apt/sources.list && cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*list`. Maybe you have some version mixup?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223237/unable-to-correct-problems-you-have-held-broken-packages)